# Cannot get fabric8 to start on local development machine (OSX or Linux)

Tags: minikube, fabric8

I'm trying to give fabric8 a shot but I'm having issues getting it to start on a local machine running minikube and virtualbox (I've attempted this on Linux and OSX. I'm able to get all but one of the pods to start (after manually increasing minikube's VM ram to 8GB). The expose controller won't start and is giving me the following error in the logs:

I0415 14:29:43.431944       1 exposecontroller.go:47] Using build: '2.3.2'

F0415 14:29:43.492059       1 exposecontroller.go:66] failed to create new strategy: failed to create node port expose strategy: failed to list nodes: nodes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:fabric8:exposecontroller" cannot list nodes at the cluster scope

Here are the commands I'm running:

```
minikube start --cpus=5 --disk-size=50g --memory=8000
curl -sS http://get.fabric8.io/download.txt | bash
gofabric8 start
```

I also tried creating OAuth secret via GitHub (using bogus IP address info for the redirect URL) but this doesn't make sense to me because I don't have a domain... Then I ran these:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=xhyve --cpus=5 --disk-size=50g --memory=8000
minikube addons enable ingress
gofabric8 deploy --package system -n fabric8
```

That resulted in the exposecontroller working but then additional pods (keycloak, for example) were created but failed to start.

I've spent hours trying to get this to work and am about to give up. The documentation on GitHub differs from fabric8's site documentation and I just can't get it to work. If someone is able to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Note:

I've attempted to follow the instructions here:
http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gofabric8.html

Additionally, I attempted to follow this:
https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-platform/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: Can you please add some more details on how the pods are failing? Do you see anything in the logs or the events?

Comment: This is a know problem and didn't get fixed since Nov, 2017. Here is the issue in github project: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-platform/issues/1185